# where the root of $f(x) $ belong?

Tags: polynomials, roots

let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z[x]}$ be  a  monic polynomial.then root  of  $f $

choose the correct options

$1.$ can belong to $\mathbb{Z}$

$2.$ always belong  to ($\mathbb R$ \   $\mathbb{Q} )\cup  \mathbb{Z}$

$3.$always belong  to ($\mathbb C$ \   $\mathbb{Q} )\cup  \mathbb{Z}$

$4.$ can belong to ($\mathbb{Q}$ \ $\mathbb{Z})$

My attempts : i take $f(x) = x^2 -1$ then root  will belong to $\mathbb{Z}$,so option 1 is obiously  true

here im confusing about  the  other options

Any Hints/solution will appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: For option 4, you have the *rational roots theorem*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) that all rational roots of such a polynomial are in fact integers. So, the third option is true and the fourth option is false. And $x^2+1$ shows that the second option is false too.

Comment: @  jose sir   option 4  i have  doubt  that (Q\Z) =  Q...now suppose  if i take $ f(x) =  x^2   - 1$ , then  it will true ..i mean  option 4  will true ..

Comment: @stupid Why do you say that $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb Q$? This is not true. The set $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of non-integer rationals.

Comment: ookks  thanks  u  @jose sir

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

A consequence of the *rational roots theorem* is that a rational root of a *monic* polynomial in $\mathbf{Z}[X]$ is necessarily an integer.